# TalkBack doesn't work in my own application

Tags: android

I have enabled TalkBack in Ice Cream Sandwich. And it doesn't speak buttons,list views in the application I have developed.Why is that?

Comment: have you got any sample code?

Comment: ya i have a huge code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:contentDescription` attributes to your widgets for them to be accessible via TalkBack. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html):

> Add descriptive text to user interface controls in your application using the android:contentDescription attribute. Pay particular attention to ImageButton, ImageView and CheckBox.

Comment: i'll try.thanx CommonsWare

Comment: I tried this for ImageButton.But it didn't work.This is my code        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/selectBus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/imageshyjyjy" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/byBus"/>